# Plot density histogram with facet_wrap in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, facet-wrap

I am having some issues with plotting density histograms in ggplot, when I have multiple groups that I plan to plot with facet_wrap. My data looks like this:

```
label model   probability
0     model1  0.00000005
0     model2  0.00000788
0     model1  0         
0     model2  0.00000017
0     model1  0.00000005
0     model2  0.00000137
```

I have 4 models total and 2 labels (0, 1), so I want to produce a plot with 4 subplots, 1 for each model, where the probability is binned in a density histogram and the labels have different colors. My code at the moment is:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=probability, y=after_stat(density), fill=factor(label))) +
  geom_histogram(bins=50, alpha=0.5) +
  facet_wrap(facets = vars(model), nrow=2, ncol=2) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name='True label', labels=c('0','1')) +
  labs(x='Probability of 1', y='Density')
```

So far, I am getting the facet_wrap correct, but the density is messed up. Depending on the number of bins, I can get a maximum density ranging from 50 to 150, and since my models have different sizes (model1 and model2 have almost twice as many samples as model3/model4), the y-values are very different. The figure I've attached is for the code shown above.[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the `facet_wrap(..., scales = "free_y")` argument?

Comment: No, although that looks a bit neater than this. I want all the y-axis values to lie between 0 and 1 as a density. The "free_y" argument just allows the y-axis between the plots to be different.

Comment: Densities integrate to 1. So if your only x-bin spans 0.1 units, you need 10 y-axis units of density to have it integrate to 1. I also don't think the number of observations per model matters, exactly because densities integrate to 1 (though I agree the distribution is very different). That said, are you looking for `y=after_stat(ndensity)` then? This option scales the maximum to 1.

Comment: Great answer, I completely spaced on my basic probability training. Yikes. Thanks again, this is exactly what I was looking for.